# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_celery_beat' in Django even if is installed and running

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to see the Beat statistics in the admin panel so I want to have the beat in included in settings.py but even if it installed and works (async tasks not related to the web interface), I cannot add the django_celery_beat to the INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'apps.app',
'apps.pps',
'apps.taskmgr',
'django_celery_beat',
'django_celery_results',
```

]

```
        import_module(entry)
  File "c:\users\paul\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_celery_beat'
```

I use Python 3.8, celery 5.1.2, django-celery-beat 2.2.1, Django 3.26 and running on Windows 11.

Comment: are you using virtual env ?

Comment: yes, I am using virtualev

Comment: check the package is installed in your virtual env or not `pip freeze`